# POST array in android AsyncHttpClient to php

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, post

I want to POST an android array (or list) to a php page and then insert all element of the array in a mysql table. I'm using the AsyncHttpClient library.

Now I'm using this code:

```
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                    for ( String element: elements) {                 
                                params.add("elements[]", element);       
                    }
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

client.post(context, "https://aaaaa.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        try {
            //mycode
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
    }

});
```

But I don't know if it is the correct method. How I can get my android array in a php page?

Comment: Just to be clear... The problem is on the PHP side? And a tip, link the lib you're using.

Comment: This is the library that I'm using: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/
The biggest problem is on the PHP side, but I'm not sure that I'm doing the right thing in android.

Comment: I got it working here. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it seems you're having some trouble on both ends. So let's solve them both.

First, on your android side, declare the internet permission on your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

There's nothing wrong with the rest of your code, I've used exactly the same thing, and it worked just fine.

Now, to the PHP end. You want to receive the data through `POST`, for that you will need to use the super global variable `$_POST` to fetch that data, which you can read more about [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). And later, I'm using `mysqli` to save that data on a database, you can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

**Your_file.php**

```
<?php
    $elements = $_POST['elements'];

    if (isset($elements)) {
        $count = count($elements);
        $i = 0;
        $mysqli = new mysqli("hostName","user","password","DbName");

        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $element = $elements[$i];
            // Here you can call a function to save this $element on your database. Like the example below.


            if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                die('Error while connecting to database');
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO Table (`column_name`) 
                    VALUES ('$element');";

            $mysqli->query($sql);
        }

        $mysqli->close();
    }
?>
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: This solution don't work for me.. I wrong something in android?

Comment: You are very welcome! Don't forget to mark the question as accepted, and upvote it if you can ;)

Comment: @Mauker, I tried your solution and it worked also for me. I have only one question regarding the RequestParams and the order of the elements. I have `params.add("elements[]", val1)` and `params.add("elements[]",val2)`. When I print in $elements[0] from the PHP code, I get val2 when I would expect val1. Any idea for this?

Comment: @Konstantinos I believe (unconfirmed) that you can't guarantee the order when you do that. One workaround would be to pass your data as a JSON, and on the PHP side you could read that JSON.

Comment: thanks for the reply. JSON seems to be the way to go.